# Module @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest should have "jest-preset.js" or "jest-preset.json" file at the root

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-cli

I've set up my project in a project containing only folder with icons inside with the following commande `vue create .`

I've selected Jest for testing and done nothing more
When I run `npm run test:unit` I have the following output

```
● Validation Error:

  Module @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest should have "jest-preset.js" or "jest-preset.json" file at the root.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html
```

Anyone ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you share a link to a GitHub repo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: This is a private repo I can't sorry, it seems there is a problem with my npm/node versions with quasar

Comment: @MounirOnGithub did u managed to figure it out? i'm having the same issue

Comment: Are u still using Quasar ? If so, maybe the issue is with quasar v2 I've used the v1 version and everything went ok

Comment: Hi @tony19, I've the same issue and this is [my repo](https://github.com/Daniele-Tentoni/fowdecks-client) if can help. I'm trying to use `npm run test:unit` and the result is:
    
    > fowdecks-client@0.1.0 test:unit
    > vue-cli-service test:unit --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile=./tests/setup.js
    
    ● Validation Error:
    
    Module @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest should have "jest-preset.js" or "jest-preset.json" file at the root.
    
    Configuration Documentation:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi even I was facing the same issue.

I just updated the @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest package and it worked for me.

My Vue version is
2.6.11

and I updated @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest to @4.5.0

```
npm -i -s @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest@4.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```js
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
```

with this:

```js
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.js?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
```

Then run:

- `npm install --save-dev vue-jest jest-transform-stub babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0`
- `npm uninstall @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest`